# Replacing capacitor across power input to VS1838B infrared sensor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, decoupling-capacitor

[image: VS1838B Breakout Board Diagram]

This is a schematic of VS1838B infrared sensor. The problem is that I don't have a 10 uF capacitor. Can I replace it with a 100 uF / 1 uF electrolytic capacitor?

Kindly also explain its purpose; is it only for decoupling or does it also form a separate filter, like the 100 ohm and 0.1 uF one?

Also, if I have several of these sensors, can I just use these components once, make the VCC and ground common to all the sensors and hook up the output to Vcc individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the reference design in the datasheet of the manufacture, yes you can. It is also mentioned that the pull up resistor \$R_2\$ should be bigger than \$20k\Omega\$.

The combination  of \$R_1\$, \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ is probably being used as a filter as well, preventing the carrier's frequency from being coupled back into the supply voltage of the microcontroller.

Each sensor should have their own decoupling capacitor / filter, otherwise their efficiency would drop, meaning:

1. The decoupling capacitor would not be able to provide enough current to all sensor if they were active at the same time
2. The magnitude of the carrier frequency being coupled back would increase if they were activie at the same time

[image: circuit]

[Source](http://eeshop.unl.edu/pdf/VS1838-Infrared-Receiver-datasheet.pdf)

Comment: what if i have multiple sensors, do i have to add these components for each sensor, or can i just make the circuit once and connect vcc and gnd and pull up each sensor to it?.

Comment: @HermanZahid I just updated my answer.

Comment: ok that answers my question, one more thing i wanted to ask is that since frequency/noise plays a part in all of this, can i use the same voltage source for every sensor?

Comment: If they are all decoupled from each other through a filter / cap, yes, I asuume there should be no problems.

Answer (score 0):

The capacitors are for filtering power supply noise and for bypassing. Larger capacitance makes a better filter, but no ceramic 100nF makes the bypassing a bit worse. But it is mainly an analog chip so it should not take large current spikes, and the datasheets do not explicitly say anything about requiring a 100nF ceramic.

You can use the filtered power for several IR receivers, if the total current consumption is low enough that there is enough supply voltage.